# Problems with error_log and Log Rotation

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, centos5

**Error_log**

---

My error_log is now at 40MB. I would like to reduce this file size.

I'm trying to locate the error log so that I can edit and remove content of the file.
But that's easier said than done.

In my httpd.conf file, the location of the log file is set to `logs/error_log`.
But I'm not able to locate any folder called `logs`.

I do have the folder `var/log/httpd/`, but the largest error_log file is only at 670KB.

So how can I reduce the filesize of my error_log?

**Log Rotation**

---

I discovered that Log Rotatio was switched off. So I switched this on and set the size to be about 4MB. But today, the log file was still at 40MB.

Now I have set it to log Weekly and maksimum of 52 files.

But when does this come in effect? When does it create a new log file? It obviously did not do that when I set it to maks 4MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To find out where is the logs
  directory, you have to search for the
  ServeRoot directive, under the
  ServerRoot you will normally have the
  logs directory.
- If you want your changes to take
  effects, you have to restart the
  Apache server process every time you
  change the configuration.
- You can even specify the full path of
  the error_log and even a name you
  like more:

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
  or
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/idontlikeerrors_log

**Edit**

A note for whom works with Plesk

> Customizable httpd.include per domain
>
> In Plesk each domain has virtual hosts
>   configuration stored in a separate
>   file:
>
> /home/httpd/vhosts//conf/httpd.include
>
> This file is overwritten each time the
>   virtual host configuration is changed,
>   thus any manual alterations made to
>   the file are discarded. To use custom
>   directives or redefine those inserted
>   by Plesk, you need to create the files
>   vhost.conf and/or vhost_ssl.conf with
>   necessary directives in the directory
>   /home/httpd/vhosts//conf/
>
> If any (or both) of these files exist
>   by the time the main configuration
>   file is generated, Plesk inserts the
>   appropriate directive Include
>   /home/httpd/vhosts//conf/vhost.conf
>   or Include
>   /home/httpd/vhosts//conf/vhost_ssl.conf
>   into the HTTP and/or HTTPS virtual
>   host context respectively.
>
> For security reasons, only root can
>   create the vhost.conf and
>   vhost_ssl.conf files.
>
> For the changes to take effect, you
>   need to run the following:
>
> /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng
>   --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=

Comment: Ah, the reset it is. I'm using plesk (not Telnet), so I don't think I have the search option. Should I change path of ErrLog in `httpd.conf` or in `httpd.include` ?

Comment: @steven I don't know well Plesk (I know apache), but I think it's http.include